# Download file not working well in safari with PHP

Tags: php, safari, cross-browser

The code below is working well with all browsers but extension not show in safari.
Maybe Content Type Issue ?

```php
public function CheckRoutingURLAction($filename){
    $filename = 'https://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2019_41/3047866/191010-japan-stalker-mc-1121_06b4c20bbf96a51dc8663f334404a899.fit-2000w.JPG';

try{
        $content = file_get_contents($filename, true, stream_context_create(array(
            "ssl" => array(
                "verify_peer" => false,
                "verify_peer_name" => false,
            ),)));
    }
    catch (\Throwable $e){
        $logger = $this->get('logger');
        $logger->err($e->getMessage());
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page not found');
    }

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'mime/type');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition',
        'attachment;filename=Noman.png'));
    $response->setContent($content);
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, that work in all browsers for me :)

```
        $response->headers->set('Content-Description',' File Transfer');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition',' attachment; filename=' . $quoted);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding',' binary');
        $response->headers->set('Connection',' Keep-Alive');
        $response->headers->set('Expires',' 0');
        $response->headers->set('Cache-Control',' must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        $response->headers->set('Pragma',' public');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Length', $size);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', mime_content_type($filename));
        $response->setContent($content);
        return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this code. I always use this one to download external files.

```
$filename = 'https://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2019_41/3047866/191010-japan-stalker-mc-1121_06b4c20bbf96a51dc8663f334404a899.fit-2000w.JPG';

$file = basename($filename);

header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

readfile($filename);
```

Comment: I can't give the basename , Name should be random number with file extension, I have different files may be , csv, jpeg, pdf, txt ,.doc etc  
So the solution should be generic that generate random number and attached file extension